# Merge/Embed .NET framework

Tags: c#, vb.net, frameworks, mono, runtime

I like to know how I can embed the .NET framework in my .NET application, so I can run it on any windows computer, without having the .net framework installed.
I know that it is possible somehow, I tried mono, with no success, because the -mno flag got removed in the newer compilers.

I also know that the filesize will increase a lot, but that doesn't matter for me.
Any other possibilities to merge/embed the framework than mono?

I tried Spoon Studio, but I am not so sure how to use it exactly to embed the framework.
I don't want the app to run under linux, Windows is perfectly fine, but the exe should include the framework.

Answer (score 2):

I know of two more or less easy possibilities:

1. Most common: Just add the .NET FW to your installer and let him install it if not present
2. Not yet out: [.Net Native](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/dotnetnative&ei=zkNaU-KBAqPpywOJ5oCwBQ&usg=AFQjCNFvqqc4DxMfPQyOUzTyFQJH4ZrKsQ&sig2=GGAXHkGMAqHYMoLTXQO42Q&bvm=bv.65397613,d.bGQ) - I think this is more or less exactly what you search

Comment: Well since .net native is not out yet for windows forms apps, I like to bundle the framework into the executable. Is there a way to do this with mono, with the new compilers aswell? Since there were a lot changes, compared to the old compielrs...

Comment: "Embed it in the exe" does not work (without hacks) AFAIK, but every half decent installer should bring that feature...

Comment: Hm, well, if possible I like to embed the framework directly without an installer... And Mono makes so much problems with the latest compilers...

Comment: As already said: The .NET FW does not support that. .NET Native is the upcoming solution for such cases...

Comment: And what do you mean by "hacks"...?

Comment: Yes, but not for such stuff. Why do you even want this so desperately?

Comment: I need this for my dad. His program need to run on his company pc, he has only limited privileges there and is not allowed to install other programms n stuff. On this pc there is no .net framework. So i like to compile with mono and implement all dependencies (.net framework) so i only have a standalone executable which can be started then

Comment: `On this pc there is no .net framework.`?!? Are they still using XP? Because Vista or newer have at least 2.0 installed (3.0/3.5 by default, but can be deinstalled).

Comment: it is windows xp. I like to merge the framework with the binary, or at least compile the vb.net app with mono and then merge the mono dependencies